# Does Juno have enough fuel to push itself into a more elliptical orbit reaching out to Himalia?

Tags: fuel, orbital-maneuver, gravity-assist, juno

Does the Juno probe have enough fuel to push itself into a highly elliptical orbit around Jupiter so that its apojove would be at Himalia's orbital distance to study Himalia better? Would a gravity assist from another moon, e.g. Ganymede, help Juno achieve an orbit reaching out to Himalia?

Comment: How is this post different from your other post?

Comment: @NilayGhosh By the fact that the other post focused on using Jupiter for gravity-assist which was explained to be impossible because Juno _is_ in a Jovian orbit already. This post focuses on the fuel and therefore I wrote in the other post that I'll ask a question on this. However, Heopps already answered this as well in a comment so I can redirect this question there.